# How to open .lmesh and .lanim files?

Tags: 3d, blender

I try to open league of legends models using Blender, but I don't know how to handle .lmesh and .lanim files. These files are located in here: http://static.lolking.net/shared/mv/

Comment: A search turns up [an open source 3D renderer called lmesh](http://lmesh.sourceforge.net/). Perhaps a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

The LMesh used by lolKing is not the actual format used by League of legends; if you look in the RAF archive in your league of legends installation, the files are using .SKN extension. The SKN format is well-documented by various open-source viewers such as [LolBlender](https://code.google.com/p/lolblender/wiki/fileFormats). I don't think the existing tools are fully updated for the latest version though, so you might have to do some legwork yourself modifying the import/export scripts. The Maya importer seems to be the only one that is actively updated.

I took a look at the LMESH file to compare it with the corresponding SKN, and there are differences in encoding. For example, strings are lenghth-prefixed instead of fixed-size. I'm not sure you'll find a whole lot of documentation but it seems fairly straightforward enough to reverse-engineer by comparing to the original.